# sql query that groups different items into buckets

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query that returns the count of items whose price falls into certrain buckets:

For example if my table is:

```
item_name | price
i1        | 2
i2        | 12
i3        | 4
i4        | 16
i5        | 6
```

output:

```
range   | number of item
0 - 10  |  3
10 - 20 |  2
```

The way I am doing it so far is

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM my_table
Where price >=0
and price <10
```

then

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM my_table
Where price >=10
and price <20
```

and then copy pasting my results each time into excel.

Is there an automatic way to do this in an sql query?

Comment: What DBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle...)?

Comment: Your ranges should be 0-9, 10-19, etc.

Comment: I am very new to SQL, the program I am using is called interactive sql - I hope this answers the question of the database I am using.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

An expanded option from what Kerrek described, you can do you grouping based on a case/when

```
select
      case when price >= 0 and price <= 10    then '  0 - 10'
           when price > 10 and price <= 50   then ' 10+ - 50'
           when price > 50 and price <= 100  then ' 50+ - 100'
           else 'over 100'
      end PriceRange,
      count(*) as TotalWithinRange
   from
      YourTable
   group by 1
```

Here, the "group by 1" represents the ordinal column in your select statement... in this case, the case/when as TotalWithinRange.

Comment: When running your samply of the code, one of the fields I am getting is a Null field as one of the price range, the remaining fields are the ranges I am specifying. All in all, this is really helpful! I tried Kerrek's solution, I understand the concept but I am getting some errors when I try to run the Concat function.

Comment: So just to confirm, saying "group by 1" tells it to group by "PriceRange" but without having to rewrite the definition of pricerange?

Comment: @PrinceM, correct... In this case, 1 is the ordinal column in the select columns list.  If you had something like select Country, sum(someCondition) as TotalThings from TableX group by Country order by 2, the 2 represents TotalThings which is the second ordinal column.  The group by is similar context.

Comment: @DRapp Makes sense, thank you for your response. It would be nice if once the title name was specified in SELECT clause (e.g. PriceRange as above) it could be referred to in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, etc. as with the dplyr grammar of R. I am new to SQL for work purposes and used to R, still a beginner.

Answer (score 37):

You can try grouping by 10 units of price:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS tally,
       FLOOR(price/10) AS prange,
       CONCAT(10*FLOOR(price/10), "-", 10*FLOOR(price/10)+9) AS rstr
FROM my_table
GROUP BY prange;
```

Comment: That's the idea. You could, however, be required to tweak your answer when OP let us know the RDBMS.

Comment: @Adrian: I don't know standard-SQL entirely, but is there anything non-standard in my query?

Comment: CONCAT() as an aggregate function is specific to Oracle and MySQL, I believe. (You're also missing a comma after `prange`)

Comment: Also, aliasing `prange` and mentioning it by name in `GROUP BY` would not be available in some RDBMS

Comment: And Access for one doesn't support FLOOR I don't think. Have to use INT I think.  Google is showing "interactive sql" by microOLAP as PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Comment: thx for the code, unfortunately, I am not able to run the Concat function. But I think I understand the concept behind what  you wrote :)

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback -- the CONCAT was an optional gimmick, you can produce that label string elsewhere. If there's no FLOOR, maybe you have an INT or ROUND or TRUNC... Fixed the comma, too :-)

Comment: Thank you, was able to adapt your solution to my use case.  Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

A bit of modification of DRapp's code...

```
select
case when price >= 0 and price < 10    then "  0 - 10"
           when price > 10 and price <= 50   then " 10+ - 50"
           when price > 50 and price <= 100  then " 50+ - 100"
           else "over 100"
end As PriceRange,
count(item_name) as ItemTotal
from YourTable
group by 
case when price >= 0 and price < 10    then "  0 - 10"
           when price > 10 and price <= 50   then " 10+ - 50"
           when price > 50 and price <= 100  then " 50+ - 100"
           else "over 100"
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple mysql solution. First, calculate the bucket index based on the price value.

```
select *, floor(price/10) as bucket from mytable
```

```
+------+-------+--------+
| name | price | bucket |
+------+-------+--------+
| i1   |     2 |      0 |
| i2   |    12 |      1 |
| i3   |     4 |      0 |
| i4   |    16 |      1 |
| i5   |     6 |      0 |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Next, group by the bucket index and calculate sum of price and format the prange column.

```
select concat(bucket * 10, '-', (bucket * 10 - 1) + 10) as prange, count(price)
from  (select *, floor(price/10) as bucket from mytable) t1 
group by bucket;
```

```
+--------+--------------+
| prange | count(price) |
+--------+--------------+
| 0-9    |            3 |
| 10-19  |            2 |
+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using decode in orderBy:**

```
select
case when price >= 0 and price < 10    then "  0 - 10"
           when price > 10 and price <= 50   then " 10+ - 50"
           when price > 50 and price <= 100  then " 50+ - 100"
           else "over 100"
end As PriceRange,
count(item_name) as ItemTotal,
customer_name,
cust_address,
cust_sigid
from YourTable
group by 
case when price >= 0 and price < 10    then "  0 - 10"
       when price > 10 and price <= 50   then " 10+ - 50"
       when price > 50 and price <= 100  then " 50+ - 100"
       else "over 100"
end
order by
decode((case when price >= 0 and price < 10    then "  0 - 10"
           when price > 10 and price <= 50   then " 10+ - 50"
           when price > 50 and price <= 100  then " 50+ - 100"
           else "over 100"
end),"  0 - 10", 1, " 10+ - 50", 2, " 50+ - 100", 3, "over 100", 4, 5) ASC;
```

Decode works in a fashion in which it takes expression in the first argument and then subsequent key-value pairs and then finally a default value.

**Documentation:**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm