# MySQL query to group data into different ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

I found a solution for this here,
[sql query that groups different items into buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669730/sql-query-that-groups-different-items-into-buckets)

It works well as long as there is data for all the ranges. I want the query to return 0 if there is no data.

So if my table is:

```
item_name | price
i1        | 2
i2        | 22
i3        | 4
i4        | 26
i5        | 44
i6        | 6
```

I want output as:

```
range   | number of item
0 - 10  |  3
11 - 20 |  0
21 - 30 |  2
31 - 40 |  0
41 - 50 |  1
```

The below query will not display result for the 0 count cases.

```
select
      case when price >= 0 and price <= 10    then "  0 - 10"
           when price > 10 and price <= 20   then " 10 - 20"
           when price > 20 and price <= 30   then " 20 - 30"
           when price > 30 and price <= 40  then " 30 - 40"
           when price > 40 and price <= 50  then " 40 - 50"
           else "over 50"
      end PriceRange,
      count(*) as TotalWithinRange
   from
      YourTable
   group by 1
```

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: you have a display problem. the base query is trivial: `select cast(price / 10 as int), count(*) from yourtable group by cast(price / 10 as int)`, then using some client-side code to format the cast value into your range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build an inline table containing all price ranges. Then perform a `LEFT JOIN` with a derived table based on your query to get the expected result:

```
SELECT x.PriceRange, COALESCE(TotalWithinRange, 0) AS TotalWithinRange
FROM (
  SELECT "0 - 10" AS PriceRange 
  UNION SELECT "10 - 20"
  UNION SELECT "20 - 30"
  UNION SELECT "30 - 40"
  UNION SELECT "40 - 50"
  UNION SELECT "over 50" ) x
LEFT JOIN (  
   SELECT
      CASE when price >= 0 and price <= 10 then "0 - 10"
           when price > 10 and price <= 20 then "10 - 20"
           when price > 20 and price <= 30 then "20 - 30"
           when price > 30 and price <= 40 then "30 - 40"
           when price > 40 and price <= 50 then "40 - 50"
           else "over 50"
      END AS PriceRange,
      COUNT(*) as TotalWithinRange
   FROM YourTable
   GROUP BY 1 ) y ON x.PriceRange = y.PriceRange
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f351/6)

Answer (score 0):

Group by `TotalWithinRange`, so it will count each category

Comment: I cannot group on TotalWithinRange, Results in SQL error

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient answer, but you can try separate `SUM(CASE)` statements for each group. For example:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN price >= 0 AND price <= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "0-10"
```

And so on. That should print even the categories with SUMs of 0.