# Is storing rank values in relational table a good idea?

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have read some question related to this but they do not picture exactly my cenario. I have a table that has a column representing the number of views of the item; lets say 1000, 20. I want to give it a rank based on the number of views. So when I sort the results I want sort them by rank instead of being too much mathematical and position an item above another only because it has one view more than the other.

```
item
id view view_rank (is the view_rank here a bad practice? Why?)
1   1000   3
```

I want to do this because if don't do so I will have to use write a raw sql instead of using my ORM.
Also consider retrieving 100.000. Using a rank function for 100.000 can be significant.

Comment: Why not just order by the views?  I don't see why a separate ranking is needed.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: don't store information that can (easily) be calculated from existing data. Storing derived information usually only makes sense if calculating the information ("on the fly") is too slow for whatever you want to do with it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question - if you're not going to sort by views "mathematically", how else would you sort?

But to answer your question - if the rank is something you can derive from the data in the table, e.g. the number of views, storing that rank is duplicating the data, and that's generally a bad idea. Especially because adding a new record, or updating the number of views on a record, could mean you have to re-calculate all the rank values in the table.

If you want to group records together - e.g. 0 - 100, 101 - 500, 501 - 10000 - you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669730/sql-query-that-groups-different-items-into-buckets) to see how to do it in raw SQL; your RDBMS may have built-in features too.